# I imported two tables into Microsoft SQL Server but one of them is not being detected by intellisense

Tags: sql-server

I Imported 2 tables into Microsoft SQL Server, I am able to perform operations on both the tables but the second table is not being detected by intellisense. I am able to perform queries using the second table, except the below one.

The code that I am trying to execute is this.

```
SELECT
    dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, 
    vac.new_vaccinations,
    SUM(CONVERT(int, vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.Location 
                                                  ORDER BY dea.location, dea.Date) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated,
    --, (RollingPeopleVaccinated/population)*100
FROM
    PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths dea
JOIN
    PortfolioProject..CovidVaccinations vac ON dea.location = vac.location
                                            AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE
    dea.continent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    2, 3
```

I am getting the error that I need to convert the data type of a column, I am doing it using this code `SUM(CONVERT(int, vac.new_vaccinations))` but that is not being detected.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you refreshed intellisense? I would suggest you have not.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: "I am getting the error that I need to convert the data type of a column," - what error? I don't remember seeing intellisense say things like that? Can you provide a screenshot so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: Please add table definitions and full error message as text.